# Is there some sort of canonical edn response we can use for ring?

Tags: clojure, ring, edn

I've been reading the edn spec and want to integrate it into my application. However, I don't know how to transfer edn requests between clojure and client. Do we put a content-type application/edn in the response header and just send the prn output string?

Comment: Maybe this project by fogus can give you a starting point or some guidance: [ring-edn](https://github.com/fogus/ring-edn).

Comment: See also [ring-middleware-format](https://github.com/ngrunwald/ring-middleware-format).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it has not yet been accepted by [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types) (June 14, 2013), the correct content-type is `application/edn`.  To provide a valid string output of your clojure object, use `(pr-str obj)`.  For a web service, the method of encoding and decoding depends on your web framework and your needs.

[Pedestal](http://pedestal.io/) supports parsing of edn into an `:edn-params` key on its request map through the use of its `body-params` interceptor.  Sending clojure objects as edn is handled automatically if your response bodies are not strings.  For content-negotiation, see [pedestal-content-negotiation](https://github.com/ToBeReplaced/pedestal-content-negotiation).

For ring middleware, [ring-edn](https://github.com/fogus/ring-edn) parses edn into an `:edn-params` key, but does not do any outbound modification.  [ring-middleware-format](https://github.com/ngrunwald/ring-middleware-format) provides parsing of a handful of different formats into the `:body-params` key, and has a collection of middlewares that can be helpful for responses as well.  There are a handful of other ring middleware projects like this out there.